# javascript regexp not matching string as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

Considering the following two snippets of javascript code, I expect both t1 and t2 be evaluated to false.

```
var p1 = /^\W*(Port )?(\d+)((X\d+)+)\W*$/
var t1 = p1.test("1X2X")
var m1 = p1.exec("1X2X")    // return null (as expected)

var p2 = /^\W*(Port )?(\d+)((\/\d+)+)\W*$/
var t2 = p2.test("1/2/")
var m2 = p2.exec("1/2/")    // return ["1/2/", undefined, "1", "/2", "/2"]
```

But when I run the code in Firefox (17.0), t1 is evaluated to false (as expected), but t2 is evaluated to true. Could someone provide some light on why t2 is evaluated to true?

Comment: After omitting all optional parts, `/^\W*(Port )?(\d+)((\/\d+)+)\W*$/` becomes `/^()(\d+)((\/\d+)+)\W*$/`. Now, it's trivial to see that this matches your input `"1/2/"` (`\W` matches the last slash).

Comment: But then why does the first one return `null`? does `\W` not match the `"X"`?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Because there's a X in the pattern of p2, not found in the input string? `\W` == `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`, so X does not match `\W`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen `\W` does not match `X`. `\W` is the opposite of `\w`.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen `\W` matches a slash but not an X.

Answer (score 0):

`\W` matches `/` but not `X` because `\W` is `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

This is where the regex101.com debugger could help you: http://regex101.com/r/tK8cV1/#debugger

Here's a screenshot of the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8lED.jpg

This shows you exactly how your regex is being matched. This is however ran with PCRE, but is never the less accurate for your application still.

I hope this helps.